# Huge number of activites

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want to create a Android app for learning English letters, I created a list of letter. Do I need to create individual activity for each letter? If I do this, will the application crash or slow in performance? Because if I create a activity for each letter, I would have more than 30 activities.

Comment: Why do you need to create an activity for each letter? Why not create an activity that is responsible for receiving a letter and displaying the translation? It seems like poor practice to create 26 nearly identical activities.

Comment: 30 is not a huge number of Activity's, but I should think one Activity's would suffice. Use some kind of list widget for each letter.

Comment: The  number of Activities won't effect the performance, but it would effect developer speed and maintenance effort.  Its faster/easier to write one activity that takes the letter to display as a parameter than to make 30 copies of an activity, and fix bugs in all 30 for the rest of time.

Answer (score 0):

You should better create one `Activity` which contains a simple `TextView` to display the content, for example a letter.

Then, you pass the text you want to display to this `Activity`. For that, add code like this to the first `Activity`:

```
String letter = "A";
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LetterActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("LETTER", letter);
startActivity(intent);
```

And inside the `onCreate` method of `LetterActivity.java`, add this:

```
String letter = getIntent().getStringExtra("LETTER");
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(letter);
```

Hope this helps you.